# Gulp: 'function ()' is not assignable to parameter

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
const gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  console.log("Gulp: 'default' has launched.")
});
```

In this code, I got a warning message **"function (): Argument type Function is not assignable to parameter type Undertaker.TaskFunction"** in WebStorm.

The paramters of *task()* are `taskName` and `fn`. `fn` takes 'task *function*'. I can't understand why WebStorm mark `function ()` as unassignable argument. A lot of people seem to use `function ()` like that...

Comment: That works fine for me. Your error message mentions Undertaker.TaskFunction so it looks like you are using undertaker in some way, but your example doesn't include anything about undertaker.

Comment: @PeterHaight Thanks. I've uninstalled Undertaker and TypeScript Definitions library. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the global type references for gulp. Your IDE should use **node_modules/gulp** for type referencing.

Go to *Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> JavaScript >> Libraries.* In there you'll see **@types/gulp**. Un-tick it to disable it. Now your IDE will use node_modueles/gulp for type reference.